# Stop looping in after effect

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects

Just learning After effect 2nd question. I have download the free lower third and edited. I have knowledge of Flash and to a certain time we can type command stop(); and we can stop the looping there. How can we stop looping action in After effect. Thanks

[image]

Comment: There is no ingerent looping in after effects. You have yous set the play button to repeat. Set it to play once and it does not loop

Comment: I have posted the answer what i was looking for

Comment: you could have just accepted Martin's answer, since it contains the same information as you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had quit using After effects.. I think the last i used was 3 years back around! but I remember the way how to do so..

Click <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

this command will make one layer (composition in After effects and MovieClip in Flash).

Move the playhead (the pointer on the timeline) at the end of your animation,  At the last frame.. where you want to stop animation..

This is called  "freeze frame" in After effects, and ("Stop();" in Flash :))

Goto "Edit>Split Layer". it will trim the layer and create a duplicate layer above your selected layer... and that layer would begin right after the playhead.

Select the newly created upper layer... Right-Click and Select Freeze Frame. Or from menu  "Layer->Time->FreezeFrame".

your layer will freeze at this point.. you can extend or trim this layer as long as you want.

After posting this answer... I googled and found this link for you. Quite informative for you learner. 
https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/speed-ramps-freeze-frames-in-after-effects/

Comment: Although the rest of your answer is correct, freeze frame in AE is not the same as the "Stop" in Flash, because in AE the timeline is linear. Once you render your project you can only go forward like a video file - the rendered file itself will be a video file.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Luciano. I know that with an experience of AE since 2003. But to make the questioner easy to understand I wrote so.. did you see that "smily" there? the Questioner knew the use of "stop" in flash, so he will never forget now in AE. I hope this make sense for him. ... please take my comments in frank and light-mood ;)

Comment: look somebody "negative" the answer. :) his/her answer should be liked

Comment: Sure, I didn't see the smile there. I'm not sure why someone downvoted your answer, since it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the timeline on the bottom, you are looping the work area while previewing.

There are multiple options which you can set in the preview panel, one of which is changing the behavior for looping. The preview toolbar can be shown with `Windows > Preview` if not visible.

More details [on the Adobe help page about preview](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/previewing.html#ConfigurePreviewbehaviors).

Answer (score 2):

To stop looping in the preview. Just click this icon. Note if u cant see this icon. Beside there speaker icon. There is toggle icon.

This are other toggles
**This to for ping pong**

[image]

**This is for continuous loop**

[image]

**This is for play once**

[image]